# How can I build a choropleth map with d3.js

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, d3.js

How can I add a world map by the amount of invested funds with existing data to the web page? I am new in **d3.js** and I have a task to visualize the data on the world map with the help of flask and MongoDB.

So I am getting all data from MongoDB and return it into a new page using Flask. Here's my code.

```
MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
DBS_NAME = 'world_bank'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'bank_data'
FIELDS =  {'project_name': True, 'countryname': True, 'lendprojectcost': True, '_id': False}

@app.route('/home')
def world_bank_project():
    connection = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
    collection = connection[DBS_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
    projects = collection.find(projection=FIELDS)
    json_project = []
    for project in projects:
        json_project.append(project)
    json_project = json.dumps(json_project, default=json_util.default)
    connection.close()
    return json_project
```

Then I have simple page where I need to display the world map and include the data that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Data Visualization</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <script>
        d3.json('/home', function(error, data) {

            d3.select('body')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('p')
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.countryname + d.project_name + d.lendprojectcost
                })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is on a country level?

Comment: can you share a sample of the data that you get from your python code?

Comment: This is all data and i need only project_name,countryname and lendprojectcost from http://jsonstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/world_bank.zip

Comment: also, do you have to create the chloropleth yourself? or using an existing container and plugging data okay?

Comment: The basis for the map on d3.js: https://datamaps.github.io/

Comment: try this; easier to get started on: http://d3-geomap.github.io/map/choropleth/world/